# How to redirect URLs with the same substring to a new page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal, redirect

How to redirect URLs with the same substring to a new page

I have to redirect around 200 URLS of this type:

```
Redirect 301 /folder/page1.html       http://domain.com/new-a
Redirect 301 /folder/xyz_page1.html   http://domain.com/new-a
Redirect 301 /folder/page2.html       http://domain.com/new-b
Redirect 301 /folder/xyz_page2.html   http://domain.com/new-b
```

“page1.html”/ “xyz_page1.html” “page2.html”/ “xyz_page2.html” are similar besides the string “xyz_”

If I could write the redirect with a sort of wildcard for the string “xyz_” something like

```
Redirect 301 /folder/*page1.html   http://domain.com/new-a
Redirect 301 /folder/*page2.html   http://domain.com/new-b
```

instead of 200 URLs, I had to redirect only the half of them.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /folder/(.*)page1.html$   http://domain.com/new-a [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /folder/(.*)page2.html$   http://domain.com/new-b [R=301,L]
```

Used to work :) Let me know

Comment: Can I use RedirectMatch instead of RewriteRule? I want to put the redirect commands on the top of a Drupal root .htaccess file and not in the "RewriteEngine On" sections... just to have two separate section: the original drupal code and my redirects.

Comment: The 'RedirectMatch' is part of mod_alias, and the 'RewriteRule' stuff is part of 'mod_rewrite'. Both modules will get applied to the same URL at different points of the processing pipeline. So it's best to stick to RewriteRule because RedirectMatch may intefere with other pages ---you can just use RewriteEngine On  in two separate places of you .htaccess file e.g. two sections with Rewrite engine on   If that makes sense.

Comment: I did not know that I can use RewriteEngine On in separate places! Must I close the previous sections with a "RewriteEngine Off"?
Anyway I do not understand why RewriteRule is to prefer?

Comment: You can just say rewriteEngie On at the start of the file, no you do not need to say it off

Answer (score 2):

Use a `RewriteRule`. Make sure you have mod-rewrite enabled and put this in a `.htaccess` file at your site root

```
RewriteEngine On
RerwriteRule folder/.*page1\.html$ http://domain.com/new-a [R,L]
RerwriteRule folder/.*page2\.html$ http://domain.com/new-b [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RedirectMatch directive With regex :

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/page1\.html$       http://domain.com/new-a

RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/([^_]+)_page1\.html$ http://domain.com/new-b 

RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/page2\.html$       http://domain.com/new-a

RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/([^_]+)_page2\.html$       http://domain.com/new-b
```

Comment: You can greatly simplify this regex as shown in the other answers

Comment: I do not understand why did you use 4 Redirects?